# Can someone help me here. I'm trying to assign more than one rule to a single user based on role's names in django DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, roles

Here in my model I have multiple roles for users like HR, IT, ADMIN, FINANCE, EMPLOYEE and PROJECT_MANAGER. Purpose is to assign roles to user more than one based on role names. But I'm unable to get there.

Here are the models:

```
class UserRole(HRMBaseModel):
    HR = 'HR'
    IT = 'IT'
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN'
    FINANCE = 'FINANCE'
    EMPLOYEE = 'EMPLOYEE'
    PROJECT_MANAGER = 'PROJECT MANAGER'

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (HR, 'hr'),
        (IT, 'it'),
        (ADMIN, 'admin'),
        (FINANCE, 'finance'),
        (EMPLOYEE, 'employee'),
        (SUPER_ADMIN, 'super admin'),
        (PROJECT_MANAGER, 'project manager'),
    )
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role_name



class User(AbstractUser, HRMBaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    role = models.ManyToManyField(UserRole)
```

Here is serializers.py to create user

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):

        role_data = validated_data.pop('role')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        profile_data = {
            "display_name": validated_data['first_name'],
            "fullname": f"{validated_data['first_name']} {validated_data['last_name']}",
            "dob": None,
            "address": None,
            "country": None,
            "city": None,
            "state": None,
            "zip_code": None,
            "profile_avatar": None
        }

        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        user.role.add(UserRole.objects.get(role_name=role_data[0]))
        return user
```

Here is how I'm creating user

```
{
    "email": "test_99@admin.com",
    "first_name": "test_99",
    "last_name": "test_99",
    "username": "test_99",
    "password": "test_99",
    "role": [3]
}
```

But this is how I want to create user

```
{
    "email": "test_99@admin.com",
    "first_name": "test_99",
    "last_name": "test_99",
    "username": "test_99",
    "password": "test_99",
    "role": ["IT", "ADMIN", "HR"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there - let's modify your `create` method a bit:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):

    # pop role, should be a list ["IT", "ADMIN", "HR"]:
    role_names = validated_data.pop('role')
    
    # filter for role objects based on data in list:
    roles = UserRole.objects.filter(role_name__in=role_names)

    # other logic in create:
    user = ...
    ...

    # finally, add roles to user:
    user.role.add(*roles)
    user.save()

    return user
```